# Как в docker-compose подключить volume, который расположен на удаленном win-хоcте

Tags: docker-compose, smb

Дано:
-- Сервер на Ubuntu с docker
-- Сервер на Windows (s-filebase) с сетевой шарой //s-filebase/project/
-- На win-сервере создан локальный пользователь user с паролем pass и есть права на чтение/запись шары

На Ubuntu есть проект, который разворачивается с помощью docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    app:
        build: ./app        
        networks:
            - backend
            - frontend        
        depends_on:
            - redis        
        extra_hosts:
            - "s-database:$IP_database"
            - "s-filebase:$IP_filebase"
        volumes:
            - filebase:/app/static/temp
    redis:
        build: ./redis        
        networks:
            - backend        
networks:
    backend:
        driver: bridge
        internal: true        
    frontend:
        external:
            name: nginx-int
volumes:
    filebase:
        external: true
```

Так же создан volume с именем filebase:

```
docker volume inspect filebase
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-05-28T19:17:38Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/filebase/_data",
        "Name": "filebase",
        "Options": {
            "device": "//s-filebase/project/1/temp",
            "o": "device=s-filebase,username=user,password=pass",
            "type": "cifs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

При сборке проекта через docker-compose up получаю ошибку

```
ERROR: for app  Cannot create container for service app: failed to mount local volume: mount //s-filebase/project/1/temp:/var/lib/docker/volumes/filebase/_data, data: device=s-filebase,username=user,password=pass: invalid argument
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Подскажите, где не правильный аргумент?
Весь интернет перерыл так и не нашел причину(

Comment: Наверное правильнее удаленную файловую систему монтировать к локальному каталогу: `mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=pass,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8 //ИМЯ-КОМПЬЮТЕРА/Папка /точка/монтирования` а потому уже к контейнеру монтировать `/точка/монтирования`

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае корректно подключить папку в Ubuntu сервере через mount

> sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=pass,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 share dir_for_server

А в docker-compose добавить value на данную папку.